# how to get one column data of a table and it can be put into a column of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

how to get one column data of a table  and it can be put into a column of another table

plz tell me query

churchill

Comment: Can we add the tag `plz-send-me-teh-codez` ?

Comment: Old table name-student column name--sname

Comment: Please press the 'Edit' button to edit your question and tell us about the structure of your tables.

Comment: old table name--student column name--sname   new table name--student2 column name --sname ,,,i want to insert the sname columns datas of student to sname column of student2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO student2 (sname)
SELECT sname FROM student
```

Comment: Just for learning, how does this mis-matched data between old and new records?

Comment: Hrrm, not quite sure what you mean.  What this query would do is take values from one table an insert them into another as new records.  If there were other columns that required `not null` it would error out.

Comment: error message:--Cannot insert the value null into column ,,,column doesnot allow nulls

Comment: That will happen if there are other columns that are not accounted for.  Are you trying to insert records or update records?

Comment: i'm trying to insert records from one table column to another table column

Comment: The problem is that you have other columns besides the one you are moving over. At least one of those columns cannot have null values inserted into it and that is why you are getting the error.  Can you post the structure of the table you are inserting in?

Comment: yes thats correct i have made a duplicate table of the old table and trying to insert old table column data into the new table column ..and the new table columns fields are empty

Comment: You will need to insert all columns that have the `not null` constraint on them.  If you update your question with your table definition I can show you the query.

Answer (score 1):

please see the answer: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=83585